# Hyperlink with Navigation in a Richtextbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, hyperlink, richtextbox

How would I put a hyperlink with Navigation in a Richtextbox? Right now I have the following and it gives me this error: "XAMlParseException was unhandled"

xaml

```
<Page x:Class="SafeModeLiabilityAgreement"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500"
      Title="SafeModeLiabilityAgreement" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
    <Grid Background="White">


        <RichTextBox Margin="20,40,20,0" Name="RichTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="194" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

            <FlowDocument>

                <Paragraph>
<LineBreak/>

                    <Hyperlink Foreground="Blue" NavigateUri="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb3nY6avD8k" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                        How to manualy turn on/off safemode ?
                    </Hyperlink>


                </Paragraph>




            </FlowDocument>

        </RichTextBox>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

VB.net

```
Public Class SafeModeLiabilityAgreement
   Private Sub Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RequestNavigateEventArgs)
        Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri))
        e.Handled = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Look at the inner exception and add it if you still don't know what to do.

Comment: hyperlink should be in a `<Run>` i believe

Comment: I realize my xaml is wrong. All I am asking is how I would put a hyperlink in a richtextbox?

Comment: Inner error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing your paragraph to this

```
<Paragraph>
   <LineBreak/>
      <TextBlock>
         <Hyperlink Foreground="Blue" NavigateUri="http://www.youtube.co/watch?v=rb3nY6avD8k"   RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                        How to manualy turn on/off safemode ?
         </Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>

</Paragraph>
```

Comment: That's Ok. We are always here to help each other.