# Can I put a link into a richtextbox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, browser, richtextbox

Can I put a link into a richtextbox, that a user can click on to open a browser window?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question.  Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) Meta article about tags in question subjects, where the consensus is that they shouldn't be there.

Comment: Have you done any prior research into this?  Googled it, for example?  A few seconds with Google led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303414/c-sharp-wpf-richtextbox-clickable-hyperlinks-without-new-paragraph) previous Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389404/hyperlink-with-navigation-in-a-richtextbox